# How to calculate maxDrawdown in R

Tags: r, analytics

Im using the maxDrawdown function in the PerformanceAnalytics package

Im selecting a date column and a type doubel column to plot the maxdrawdown over those periods.

e.g.

```
   period            p/l
 2020-11-02         12.34
 2020-11-02         34.32
 2020-11-03         -0.23
  ...                ..
```

Ive run the code through

```
maxDrawdown(select(Data,dt,pl))
```

but this error is returned:

```
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

Comment: in order to help you we need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide 1. a short description of the problem without domain-specific info, just the details about data and code. 2. example data that we can copy paste on our side directly and 3. expected results, what should the end result look like with this toy data you provided. From the error message I only can guess that it's due to the fact that the input of maxDrawdown should be a time series object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(Data$pl, Data$date)
maxDrawdown(x)
```